# I cannot connect to my FTP server by FTPS with Apache FTPSClient with custom SSLContext - getting "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"

Tags: java, ftp, ftps, apache-commons-net, ftp-server

I am writing program to connecting to FTP server by FTPS.

Source code:

```
String protocol = "TLS";
String host = "192.168.5.165";
String username = "usr";
String password = "111";
String trustStorePath = "C:/TEMP/truststore";
String trustStorePassword = "111111";
int port = 990;

FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(protocol);

KeyStore trustStore = loadStore("JKS", new File(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword);
X509TrustManager trustManager = TrustManagerUtils.getDefaultTrustManager(trustStore);

SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");
ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] {trustManager}, null);

FTPSSocketFactory socketFactory = new FTPSSocketFactory(ctx);
client.setSocketFactory(socketFactory);

client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new 
PrintWriter(System.out)));
client.connect(host, port);
```

I imported server's certificate in my `trustStore`. But after run this code I got this error:

```
220 Wing FTP Server ready... (UNREGISTERED WING FTP SERVER)
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH command OK. Initializing TLS connection.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
  at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:269)
  at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:211)
  at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:183)
  at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
  at edtesb.remsenergy.FTPSTest.test(FTPSTest.java:63)
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: This looks strange. You are connecting with an explicit FTPS protocol to an implicit FTPS port 990. Can you connect with any standalone FTP client the same way? Show us the client's verbose log file.

Comment: Even if i connecting by implicit mode(FTPSClient(protocol, true)), i am getting the same error

Comment: Did you remove the `setSocketFactory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that you have overengineered it.

I'm not sure I can fully understand, what your code does, but I believe that you unintentionally double-encrypt the connection.

---

If you really want to connect to an implicit FTPS port 990, just use

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(protocol, true);
```

or as `protocol="TLS"` is the default, this will do too:

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(true);

client.connect(host); // 990 is default, with FTPSClient with isImplicit=true
```

---

Though as implicit FTPS is obsolete, you better use an explicit FTPS (if supported by your server, most do), by connecting to the default FTP port 21:

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient();

client.connect(host);
```

---

If you need a custom `SSLContext`, just use a corresponding overload of `FTPSClient`, like:

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(ctx);

client.connect(host);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.
`code`
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient();
client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
client.connect(host);
client.login(username, password);
client.execPROT("P");

FTPFile[] files = client.listDirectories();
for (FTPFile file : files) {
     System.out.println(file.getName());
}

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Yes, my server supports explicit ftps and i need to connect to the server by explicit mode. I did what you say.
`FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient();
client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
client.connect(host);
client.login(username, password);
client.execPROT("P");

FTPFile[] files = client.listDirectories();
for (FTPFile file : files) {
     System.out.println(file.getName());
}`

Comment: And i am getting this log:
`220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
AUTH TLS
234 Using authentication type TLS
USER usr
331 Password required for usr
PASS 111
230 Logged on
PROT P
200 Protection level set to P
SYST
215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
PORT 192,168,5,165,199,26
200 Port command successful
LIST
150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50964', transport: 'socket'

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
`

Comment: You now have a different problem. Most probably this one: [When using Java Apache FTPClient for FTP TLS getting “Remote host closed connection during handshake”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46631315/850848)